# mysql 5.7 on Amazon RDS getting "table foo doesn't exist"

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

After restoring a mysql backup in AWS RDS, I get "table doesn't exist":

```
Server version: 5.7.22-log Source distribution
mysql> show tables;
+----------------------------+
| Tables_in_db               |
+----------------------------+
| foo                        |
...

mysql> select * from foo;
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'db.foo' doesn't exist
```

This error is all around serverfault and stackoverflow.  The suggestion is usually to stop servers, examine files in the file system, and so on.

I don't think I have access to the server or the filesystem on AWS.  Am I hosed?

How do I even file a ticket against AWS?

**EDIT**: I removed a stray period above, because it wasn't in the real example.  This stray period (now gone) caused someone to do some amazing debugging below, but that's not my issue.

Also, I found out how to file a ticket against AWS [here](https://console.aws.amazon.com/support/cases?nc2=h_ql_cu#/create).

Comment: You have to pay for a support contract to contact AWS support. Dev support is from $50 a month, and response time is 1-2 days. When you pay for business support you get chat and faster responses, but it costs more of course. This is likely user error, permissions or something, someone should be able to help you figure it out.

Comment: Frankly, I'd wonder if there's a weird zero-width space or something in that table name.

Comment: @ceejayoz I tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/7759745/34935 (query for zero-width table), and found nothing.

Comment: @Tim It may well be user error, but I followed what seemed like a simple procedure: pick a backup, click "restore", it puts it on a new DB instance. I'm looking into the support..

Comment: The answer below has a good suggestion that makes sense. I don't think you've found a flaw that basic and fundamental in an AWS service that's probably used by millions of people.

Comment: @Tim The answer below was indeed amazing, but not my issue. I've filed a support ticket, and we'll see what they say.

Comment: In my experience (which includes over 10K Answers across multiple forums), only about 1% of the time do I suggest that the Asker file a bug report.

Answer (score 2):

I think I have recreated your problem:

```
mysql> use test
mysql> show tables;
+----------------+
| Tables_in_test |
+----------------+
| collorder      |
| collorder2     |
+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE DATABASE `test .`;
mysql> USE `test .`;
mysql> CREATE TABLE foo (x int);
mysql> SHOW TABLES;
+------------------+
| Tables_in_test . |
+------------------+
| foo              |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
mysql> USE test;
mysql> SELECT * FROM foo;
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'test.foo' doesn't exist
```

If you don't see what I did, let's try this:

```
mysql> SHOW DATABASES;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
| test               |
| test .             |
+--------------------+
```

Now is it obvious?

Do this:

```
SELECT schema_name, char_length(schema_name), hex(schema_name)
    FROM information_schema.schemata;
```

to see details.

Comment: That is amazing debugging. However, my apologies, the period in my header is a typo from my editing out the real name of the DB. When I do "show tables" in the real DB, there's no period, and when I do "show databases" there's no "db .". Again, sorry about that.

Comment: @dfrankow - Is there still a stray _space_?

Comment: I appreciate your persistence. When I type "use `db `" it says "Incorrect database name 'db '".

Comment: @dfrankow - put backtics around the name, including any spaces.

Comment: @dfrankow - Try the `SELECT` I added.

Comment: The SELECT you added shows the same entry (length and hex) in the backed-up DB (that works) as in the restored DB (that does not work).

Comment: For the curious, I posted an answer with what happened.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be that I used [some complicated directions](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4) to convert MySQL from utf8 (a trap) to utf8mb4, and broke some foreign key constraints by changing the two sides of the constraint to different types while the constraint was disabled.  I'm not blaming the directions, but it is a delicate operation.  I blame MySQL for a bad default ("utf8" is not all utf8), and no easy process to get to the right place.

These faulty foreign key constraints made the backup "succeed" but with data that couldn't be restored properly (but with no restore errors until I tried to select from the table).